# Unable to do an INSERT INTO using a SELECT where the SELECT is `information_schema`.`COLUMNS`

Tags: mysql, select, insert, information-schema

This one really stumps me. I'm trying to create a MySQL query that I can populate information into a columns table to then export into SQLite. I can populate just about anything I want, except when the SELECT statement comes from `information_schema`.`COLUMNS`.

Here's a simple example to test. I created a table called `TestTbl` in a schema called  and gave it 2 rows. The first is an AUTO INCREMENT INT id row, and the 2nd is a varchar 100 row called `Namedb`. I then run the following query.

```
INSERT INTO `tblinfoetc`.`testtbl` (Namedb)
SELECT
    `COLUMNS`.`TABLE_SCHEMA` AS `Namedb`
FROM
    `information_schema`.`COLUMNS`;
```

My message after doing this is:

```
Affected rows: 0
Time: 0.000s
```

If I run this without the INSERT INTO line, it returns the records without a hitch. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a workaround suggestion than a real solution:

Selecting from information_schema.columns works fine, so try doing the operation in two steps. First, copy the data using a client interface then insert it into the destination table from the client.

I have encountered the same problem on a windows machine running mysql 5.6.13. The query used to work with mysql 5.5. It might be related to this other [issue](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=69737)